# Proving the Weierstrass M-Test with topology

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I've encountered some theorems in analysis that are ultimately provable in a more elegant way with topology. So, is there a topological proof of the Weierstrass M-Test, ideally not using terribly advanced topology? I've looked for it and have found nothing so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The essential fact used in the proof of the $M$-test is that the space of bounded continuous functions
$$f:X\longrightarrow\Bbb R\qquad\hbox{or}\qquad f:X\longrightarrow\Bbb C$$
is complete. Completeness is beyond topology.

Comment: But it stays in the realm of metric topology. You could still give a try right?

Comment: @TroyWoo, then the answer is "see a proof of completeness of the space...".